# How to load images asynchronously to improve table view performance?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have a problem with the pictures. My table view is slow. How can I improve with an asynchronous call? In the function of the creation of the cells I have this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //IMPOSTA l'identifier della cella campione indexpath restituisce il numero della cella
    let cella = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("record_cat", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell

    if (musica.shared.id.count > 0) && (cella_select < musica.shared.id.count) {
        //label personalizzata cella con inserimento dell ARRAY IN BASE ALL'INDICE (indexPath.row indica il numero della cella quindi associa cella ad array)
        print(indexPath.row)

        cella.button_favorite.tag = indexPath.row
        cella.titolo.text = musica.shared.titles[indexPath.row]
        cella.artista.text = musica.shared.artists[indexPath.row]
        cella.logo_new.hidden = true

        let url_img = NSURL(string: "https://tuunes.co/app/upload/\(musica.shared.images[indexPath.row])")
        let data_img = NSData(contentsOfURL: url_img!)

        if (data_img != nil) {
            cella.immagine.image = UIImage(data: data_img!)
        } else {
            cella.immagine.image = UIImage(named: "cover-img-list")
        }

    } else {
        return cella
    }

    return cella
}
```

Comment: Table is slow because of  `let data_img = NSData(contentsOfURL: url_img!)`. Use `SDWebImage` or `KingFisher`

Comment: did it worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) via `CocoaPods`

How to use it

Import `SDWebImage` in your `ViewController` where your table is:

```
import SDWebImage
```

Then replace this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let data_img = NSData(contentsOfURL: url_img!)
if (data_img != nil){
      cella.immagine.image = UIImage(data: data_img!)
} else {
      cella.immagine.image = UIImage(named: "cover-img-list")
}
```

with

```
cella.immagine.sd_setImageWithURL(url_img!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "cover-img-list"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Set placeholder sync
cella.immagine.image = UIImage(named: "cover-img-list")

if let urlImg = NSURL(string: "https://tuunes.co/app/upload/\(musica.shared.images[indexPath.row])") {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        //load data on the background thread
        if let dataImg =  NSData(contentsOfURL: urlImg) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                //Update UI on the main thread
                cella.immagine.image = UIImage(data: dataImg)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will not cache the image